# when A prticular column has been added in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table employees where a new column named "new_emp" has been added few days back. I want to know when this column has been added. This column change may be or may not be the last alteration in the table.

I know we have all_objects table, where we can get last_ddl time. But that is not helpful for me. I want to know when exactly this "new_emp" column has been added in the employees table.

Is it possible to get the details?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Such a direct mechanism(Select from some table) does not exists in the Oracle database.

You can use

1. [DDL trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i2013) to track the DDL changes on the table. (You can create the system level trigger for all DDL changes)
2. Using the Oracle's [Audit](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023) feature

Cheers!!